# Add items one under another when space available Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following issue, I have forms with inputs inside flex-wrap, but in few forms I have `<textarea rows="5"></textarea>` and it takes more height than an input field. Is it possible to have the following structure inside flex-wrap:

Have these 2 input fields one below the other, but in their .holder divs?

https://jsfiddle.net/by06rreq/

```
CSS: 
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.holder {
  width: 30%;
}

input, textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

.holder.textarea {
  width: 65%;
}

HTML: 

<div class="flex">
  <div class="holder textarea">
      <textarea name="test" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain about desired results as screenshot or something?
it will be easier to help.

Comment: @Kumar take a look at JS fiddle, I would like to wrap both input fields one under the other, for entire row to take height of textarea. You see it puts the last input in new row, can it be in the same row, just under the first input?

Comment: Ok you can see answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what you're asking for & I can't comment due to lack of reputation so I have no option to make a guess in an answer.

So you'd like a similar layout to this?

```
-TextArea-
-Input-
-Input-
```

You could apply `display: block` and `width: 100%` to your `.holder` class, and then adjust the size of your input controls through their relevant css classes.

If I've completely misunderstood what you're trying to achieve, just comment and I'll see if I can help you further :)

EDIT:

After reading your recent comments I can offer another solution. however, it isn't using flex.

```css
.block {
  width: 100%:
  display: block;
}

.textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}

.textarea textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

.holder {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.holder input {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="textarea">
      <textarea class="textarea" name="test" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see.. Do you want like this. I have tried with multi-layout css. through `column-count`

```css
.flex {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}

.holder {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

input, textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

.holder.textarea {
  width: 65%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="holder textarea">
      <textarea name="test" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah i get that, I was just wondering if I could do it using flexbox. I will do it with css-grid if not possible with flex

Comment: Its better and recommended option. Here is code but its not fully flexible so i recommend css column for this. 

you can refer this link for flexbox http://thenewcode.com/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox